# How to map JSON to SQL Schema?

Tags: sql, sql-server, json, database-design, schema

I have a complex JSON object that I want to persist and manage/modify in a database. Is there any JSON relation managers to convert to a SQL schema, or some strategy to do this manually?

This is a sample JSON object I need a schema for:

```
{
    "action": "index.html",
    "method": "post",
    "elements":
[
{
    "type": "fieldset",
    "caption": "User information",
    "elements":
    [
        {
            "name": "email",
            "caption": "Email address",
            "type": "text",
            "placeholder": "E.g. user@example.com",
            "validate":
            {
                "email": true
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "password",
            "caption": "Password",
            "type": "password",
            "id": "registration-password",
            "validate":
            {
                "required": true,
                "minlength": 5,
                "messages":
                {
                    "required": "Please enter a password",
                    "minlength": "At least {0} characters long"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "password-repeat",
            "caption": "Repeat password",
            "type": "password",
            "validate":
            {
                "equalTo": "#registration-password",
                "messages":
                {
                    "equalTo": "Please repeat your password"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "radiobuttons",
            "caption": "Sex",
            "name": "sex",
            "class": "labellist",
            "options":
            {
                "f": "Female",
                "m": "Male"
            }
        }
    ]
]
}
```

I will probably use a key/value pair to carry them through the code, but I am thinking I need an excellent database strategy first. Any help or ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Any progress on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at [Parse JSON in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1212344/parse-json-in-c)

You should create entities for your data end then deserialize your json to these entities.

Comment: Thx.. I am checking out if LINQ to JSON would help: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikeormond/archive/2008/08/21/linq-to-json.aspx